# How I get id and total value of dynamically created text boxes?

Tags: c#, list, entity-framework, linq, dynamic

I create text boxes dynamically and use to store the data. How do I get the text boxes id and how to get total value from all text boxes?

I used this code for creating dynamic text boxes:

---

```
for (int B = 0; B < 4; B++)
        {
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            int i = TextBoxes.Count + 1;
            tb.Location = new Point(0, i * 28);
            tb.Width = 80;
            tb.Name = "ID" + i;
            tb.Text = i.ToString();
            TextBoxes.Add(tb);
            panel1.Controls.Add(tb);

        }
```

---

Comment: hope my answer helped you.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this if you are sure that all values will only hold numbers

```
var allTexboxes = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>();
var sumOfAllTextBoxes = allTexboxes.Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Text));
```

if not

```
var allTexboxes = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>();
var sum = 0;
foreach (var allTexbox in allTexboxes)
{
    if (int.TryParse(allTexbox.Text, out var i))
    {
        sum = sum + i;
    }
}
```

Comment: @HwDulanjana did it help? if it did, can you mark my answer as correct, thanks! :)